Programmatically access keycloak event log
I am currently implementing an authenticator that will be used within the reset credentials flow. Within the authenticator, I would like to make a decision based on user events that have already been recorded. By this I mean the standard user events as you can switch them on in Keycloak for recording. Specifically, I want to make the decision dependent on how often the SEND_RESET_PASSWORD event was logged for the executing user in a defined period of time.
How do I get access to the event list? I could not find a method that makes the events available.

You can access via admin API:
https://{host}:{port}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/events?type=LOGIN
(authorization required)

Is there any possibility to do that by function call? HTTP calls are always a little bit slower.
If not: Is there an easy way to do auth without the need to configure credentials before in the web ui?

Honestly I don't understand your question but as I know there is a way to make query from "event_entity" table if this is useful for you.

Okay, then I'll describe it in more detail :-)


If possible, I would prefer to access the event log without the diversions via an HTTP Rest API, since HTTP calls always mean more overhead than ‘only’ internal method calls.


If this is not easily possible, I would go the way of the Admin REST API you mentioned. For the Auth you need a token. To get a token, you first have to create a client in the Keycloak Admin UI. So you have to do that for the code to run. I thought maybe there is a way to access the API without an auth or with a simpler auth from a Keycloak extension.


